# Keep getting HTTP 500 errors Sprout SEO

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

On one of our sites that runs the Sprout SEO plugin we recently keep getting a HTTP 500 Error on the redirect + when I'm trying to create a new redirect as a 404 Page redirect or even updating an existing Redirect.

Is this a server sided issue or could this be resolved due to some settings changes?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console or on your Network tab that might help identify where the issue is coming from? 500 errors mean something is happening where Craft never even has a chance to resolve the request. If you don't feel comfortable posting the additional details here, please reach out to support: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/request/support

Comment: Not just Craft, but if it's a web server generated 500 ISE, then the underlying error message should be in your web server's error logs.

Comment: I'll have a deeper look server sided I'll post an update in a bit thanks in advance!

Comment: We found out that the issue was that the redirect / 404 page exceeded the memory limits. They still have a really high usage now but they are working as we upgraded the limits but would like to tsee this high usage goes away.. any ideas?